# putchar() weird output, why is this happening?

Tags: c, io, operator-precedence, getchar, putchar

If I type the words "Hello World" into the standard input stream, this program will print out weird box symbols instead of the expected "Hello World" back into standard output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // print out all characters from the stream until '/n' character is found
    int ch;
    while (ch = getchar() != '\n')
    {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

I am aware of how to fix the problem. But why is this line of code incorrect?

```
while (ch = getchar() != '\n')
```

Comment: You can find a list of operator precedences here by the way: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence. (Felt a bit silly posting an answer with the million that just came in. :D)

Comment: Interesting, I did not think that the operator precedence in C would differ from C# and Java.

Comment: If you're thinking of this particular case, then it seems to be the same in Java and C#. It would be bad if `x_eq_y = x == y` was interpreted as `(x_eq_y = x) == y`, as a silly example. C has some wonky precedences though (which have been acknowledged by the authors as being a mistake, but are still emulated by other languages for compatibility). For example, `x == y << z` is the same as `x == (y << z)` as you'd expect, while `x == y & z` is the same as `(x == y) & z`.

Comment: Try this in Java: (fooBoolean = fooInteger == barInteger). The == operator has higher precedence than the = operator.

Comment: @JohnH In any case, operator precedence in Java and C# differ from C's. Not the other way round ('cause C is older). Additionally in order to never fail again in precedence in C, you must remember that multiplication and division have higher precedence than addition and subtraction. Everything else needs parenthesis.

Comment: IMO this is exactly why the "single statement -> single responsibility -> single action" principle was created... so that people won't have a `WTF operator precedence` every 5 minutes. Either separate compound statements or use explicit parentheses. In any other case you're asking for trouble or forcing it upon other people.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`(ch = getchar() != '\n')` should be rewritten as

```
((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
```

Because `!=` binds tighter than `=` in [C operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Operator are not ordered from left to right (reading direction of english) as one might expect. For example result of `2 + 3 * 5` is `17` and **not** `25`. This is because `*` will be performed before performing `+`, because `*` operator has more precedence than `+` operator.

So when you write something like

```
ch = getchar() != '\n'
```

**You expect it to be equivalent to**: `(ch = getchar()) != '\n'`

**But actually it is equivalent to**: `ch = (getchar() != '\n')`

Because the result of `!=` is either `true` or `false`, you see character `\001` on screen. I believe `\001` appears as boxes<sup>1</sup> on your system.

---

<sup>1: Character `\001` may appear as a box or dot or some wierd character or it may not appear in output at all.</sup>

Comment: In reference to `For example result of 2 + 3 * 5 is 17 and not 25`....This is a great answer but, Had it been `2 * 3 + 5`, it would still be evaluated as `11` and not as `16`.. It has got to do with the `*` operator precedence over `+` than Right to Left evaluation. Some rookie would take this wrongly.\

Comment: @WedaPashi Thanks for your helpful comment, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: By the program logic, \000 will be seen "never", not "rarely". As soon as gethcar() returns '\n', ch is assigned 0 and the loob body is not executed.

Answer (score 12):

And as a slightly meta-ish answer, the overarching fix is always compiling with warnings enabled:

```
$ gcc t.c -Wall
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:7:5: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
     while (ch = getchar() != '\n')
     ^
t.c:12:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Or better yet try clang, which warns by default and generally gives better diagnostic messages:

```
$ clang t.c
t.c:7:15: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    while (ch = getchar() != '\n')
           ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
t.c:7:15: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    while (ch = getchar() != '\n')
          ^
           (                     )
t.c:7:15: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    while (ch = getchar() != '\n')
              ^
              ==
1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to be aware of [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) - comparison operators such as `!=` have a higher precedence than assignment (`=`). Use parentheses to enforce the required behaviour, i.e. change:

```
while (ch = getchar() != '\n')
```

to:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
```

---

Addendum: be sure to take heed of the advice from @TomGoodfellow in a separate answer below - using a decent compiler with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall`) would have alerted you to this problem immediately.

Answer (score 5):

Because you need to write it as `while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')`

Comment: While you're very right, you should add some description about what, how and why in your answer to make it a great one. Cheers !! :-)